# ASP.NET - Variable in custom server Control in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Why this is wrong?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterContent" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>                  
        <ArticleControlItem:ArticleControlItem runat="server" 
                Title='<%# Eval("Title") %>' ></ArticleControlItem:ArticleControlItem>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

`ArticleControlItem` is my own Web Control, and I need to set parametr (Title). The control is placed in Repeater. How do I get variable "Title" from database to parametr Title? Why do I get this error?

> CS0426: The type name ArticleControlItem does not exist in the type ArticleControlItem.ArticleControlItem.

This works perfect:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterContent" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>                  
        <ArticleControlItem:ArticleControlItem runat="server" Title="TEST" ></ArticleControlItem:ArticleControlItem>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Thank you.

Thank you for helping me. Relevant part of ArticleControlItem:

```
public string Title
{
    get
    {
        object o = ViewState["Title"];
        if (o == null) return "Default Title";
        return (string)o;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Title"] = value;
    }
}
```

Can I save value from Eval("Title") to another variable? Something like

```
string TitleFromDB = Eval("Title")
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of your `ArticleControlItem`?

Comment: Tried your code. It's working fine for me. Can you show how you have defined the `Text` property of `ArticleControlItem` UserControl?